# How can Func<out TResult> return Func<out TResult>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm toying with an undo-redo implementation, and I would like to have that an undo or redo item on its stack holds a reference to some `Func<out TResult>` where `TResult` is itself a `Func<TResult>`. The point would be that when `Func` is invoked from the undo stack, the return value is then stored on the redo stack (and vice-versa).

I'm not sure if it can be done hence this question.

The best I can come up with just won't work as you can see here:

```
struct UndoRedoItem
{
    public Func<Func<Func<Func<Func<Func<......>>>>>> UndoOrRedoFunc;
    public string Description;
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Why not create a delegate instead of using `Func<>`? Like so for example: `delegate UndoRedoAction UndoRedoAction(long param);`

Comment: Be careful with the mutable structs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have discovered, having the undo Func return the redo Func directly doesn't work, because the type argument required would grow infinitely. What you need to do is introduce a level of indirection, for example, by having the undo Func return the UndoRedoItem to be placed on the redo stack instead of just the redo Func:

```
struct UndoRedoItem
{
    public Func<UndoRedoItem> UndoOrRedoFunc;
    public string Description;
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should investigate the command pattern to achieve what you want.

One command encapsulates all information to execute a certain task.
Therefore it is easy to undo or redo it (perhaps with some overhead of
holding states that are not encapsulated inside the Command object)

Here are some links on that:

[Command pattern for undo / redo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8303/Using-the-Command-pattern-for-undo-functionality)

[Multilevel Undo / Redo in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33384/Multilevel-Undo-and-Redo-Implementation-in-C-Part)

Comment: +1 yes I was slowly but surely drifting towards using the command pattern with undo/redo. I accepted the other answer nonetheless as it answers what I asked.